# How to configure path for mod_wsgi (Python) and process the request

Tags: python, web, mod-wsgi

while I have quite some python experience, I've never used it for web and I have vast amount of web experience with PHP.

Now I want to create a simple python script (lets call it `service.py`) that runs on `example.com`. I installed mod_wsgi as suggested by the docs, my web server is Apache 2.2, the mod_wsgi is loaded successfully.

How do I configure my web server/mod_wsgi so that requests comming to `example.com/service` are processed by `service.py`?

Then how do I access the request params (like $_GET, $_POST, $_FILES) from the python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mod_wsgi, you configure which URLs are served by setting `WSGIScriptAlias`. Your script, though, needs to be an actual WSGI application, which exposes an `application` variable which is called by the server.

I suspect it'd be easier to configure your script as simple CGI. You can then use the [`cgi` module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) from the standard library to access your request params (note, though, that the examples you give are PHP-specific: they're accessed differently in Python, depending on the specific framework).

Another alternative would be to use a mini-framework like Flask, which would encapsulate all this and give you a simple interface to use in your service.py script.